# How to dynamically add conditions to .loc pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assuming that I have a pandas dataframe `df` I can use `.loc()` as below:

```
c1 = df['count'] > 10
c2 = df['min'] > 3
c2 = df['max']> 4

filtered = df.loc[c1 & c2 & c3].T.reset_index()
```

No say that the conditions are stored in a list:

```
conditions = [df['count'] > 10, df['min'] > 3, df['max']> 4]
```

How can I pass this list to the `.loc()` and indicate that all conditions must hold (`&`)?

Comment: `np.array(conditions).all(axis=1)`?

Comment: @QuangHoang Do you mean `df.loc[np.array(conditions).all(axis=1)].T.reset_index()`? If so, I get `KeyError: IndexError('indices are out-of-bounds',)`

Comment: I didn’t realize you have series. Maybe `pd.concat(conditions, axis=1).all(1)` then.

Comment: On similar lines how can I define a condition for ==, like c1 = df['count'] == 10 ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use functools reduce:

```
l = [c1,c2,c3]
from functools import reduce
df.loc[reduce(np.logical_and, l)]
```

@GZ0 improvement...

```
df.loc[np.logical_and.reduce(l)]
```

Comment: You could just use `np.logical_and.reduce(l)` instead.

Comment: @GZ0 Thanks for the improvement!

Answer (score 3):

I think `np.logical_and.reduce` should work

```
np.logical_and.reduce(conditions)
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides your current approach, another alternative for the same task is to store the conditions as strings and use `df.query` for querying.

```
conditions = ["(count>10)", "(min>10)", "(max>4)"]
result = df.query(" & ".join(conditions))
```